# How do I save a variable or function definition to a file?

Tags: export

Is it possible to save a function which was created via `Interpolation` of some data in such a way that I can use this function in a new *Mathematica* session without repeated interpolation of the data?

For example, I have some data which I interpolate in the following way:

```
exampleData={{1,1},{2,3},{3,4},{4,7},{5,5},{6,4},{7,2}};
interPolFunc[x_]:=Interpolation[exampleData,x]
```

Now one of the following would be nice:

- a way to save the interpolated function so that it can be used the next time when I work with *Mathematica* (but I do not want to interpolate the data again, so that I can delete them).
- the data and `Interpolation` command are saved in a separated notebook which is executed when I want to use my `interPolFunc` in another notebook.

Unfortunately I did not find any solution for that. But I hope that some of you have several suggestions!

Comment: It's important to know that the internal structure of an Interpolation function is not a very stable format. That is, future versions of Mathematica may use a different structure to store Interpolations which would make your saved Interpolation not work. This is the case between version 7 and version 8 because of improvements made to Interpolation in version 8.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Searke! I will keep my data in a separate notebook so that I can redo the Interpolation in the case something will be changed at the structure in the future.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use `DumpSave`:

```
exampleData = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 7}, {5, 5}, {6, 4}, {7, 2}};
interPolFunc[x_] = Interpolation[exampleData, x]
```

(note the use of `Set` (`=`) rather than `SetDelayed` so as to have the interpolating function evaluated only once; the way you had it, you interpolated each and every time).

```
DumpSave["~/Desktop/interpol.mx", interPolFunc]
```

then

```
Quit[]
DumpGet["~/Desktop/interpol.mx"]
interPolFunc[4]
(*7*)
```

Comment: You forgot the obligatory warning: MX is not cross-architecture.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. @Szabolcs: Your answer is also very helpful. But @acl made me aware of the use of `Set` instead of `SetDelayed` - a nice bonus answer. Therefore, I set his answer as accepted. @J.M. I am not so golden ;-) If I restart mathematica I would have to interpolate the data again. But with acl’s or Szabolcs’ answer I need not to.
@acl: By the way: What would you use if you work with Piecewise functions (of in mathematica in-built functions) or with self-created functions (again out of in-built functions), `Set` or `SetDelayed`? Is there any suggestion or rule for that?

Comment: thanks. regarding `Set` or `SetDelayed`, see for instance http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/704/functions-vs-patterns or http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues but I doubt you need to worry that much about it.

Comment: @partial81 Actually The first thing I wrote in my reply was a link to the tutorial on delayed vs non-delayed definitions. But this must not influence your choice of answer!

Comment: @partial: I'll put it this way: `f[x_] := Sin[x]/(1+x)` is fine. `g[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, x >= 0}}, 0]` is also fine. But, there are situations like `h[x_] = D[f, x]` that necessitate the use of `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`...

Comment: Thanks for the links! It is good to hear that this `Set` or `SetDelayed` is something I need not worry about much.
Well, it is difficult to choose among such helpful answers the best. Sometimes I would love to accept more than one answer;-)

Comment: @Szabolcs: What do you mean? If I `DumpSave` variables into a `file.mx` on Linux on aone computer and use `DumpGet` and a different Linux on different computer, should it work? What about between Linux and Windows? What about between different versions of Mathematica? Also, I couldn't find `DumpGet`, just `Get`. Is that ok?

Comment: @Leo Only if the other Linux computer runs on the same architecture. If you saved the file on x86_64, you won't be able to load it on 32-bit x86 or on a Raspberry Pi. However, the cross-platform compatibility of MX has improved since I wrote this comment. I believe you will be able to load it on 64-bit macOS or Windows (in the past this was not possible).

Answer (score 77):

I would like to describe and compare several different ways that one may save a function definition in *Mathematica*.

First, let me get out of the way how you were defining `interPolFunc` incorrectly.  First and most importantly, the use of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`) will cause rebuilding of interpolation data every time you call `interPolFunc`.  Secondly:

> [Interpolation[{*f*<sub>1</sub>, *f*<sub>2</sub>, ...}]](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html)
>       constructs an interpolation of the function
>   values *f*<sub>i</sub>, assumed to correspond to *x* values 1, 2, ...
>   .

Therefore, you should write:

```
interPolFunc = Interpolation[exampleData];
```

The output of which is an `InterpolatingFunction` object.

---

### Put

Perhaps the most basic method for saving a function or expression is [`Put`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Put.html), also written `>>`.  There is also [`PutAppend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PutAppend.html) (`>>>`) which adds to a file rather than replacing it.

> *expr* >> *filename*
>     writes *expr* to a file.
>
> Put[*expr*<sub>1</sub>, *expr*<sub>1</sub>, ..., "filename"]
>     writes a sequence of expressions *expr*<sub>i</sub> to a file.

Let's try it (the normal extension for *Mathematica* textual files is `m`):

```
interPolFunc >> "interPolFunc-Put.m"
```

The contents of `interPolFunc-Put.m` read:

> ```
> InterpolatingFunction[{{1, 7}}, {3, 1, 0, {7}, {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0},  
>  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}}, {{1}, {3}, {4}, {7}, {5}, {4}, {2}},
>  {Automatic}]
> ```

`Put` saves the `value` of the expression it is given.
  To use this one would use [`Get`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Get.html), also written `<<`, and `=`:

```
interPolFunc = << "interPolFunc-Put.m" ;
```

---

Suppose we have a function that has multiple definition rules and/or depends on additional user functions that we wish to save. Consider this number-of-permutations function `nPr`:

```
nCr[_, 0] = 1;
nCr[n_, n_] = 1;
p : nCr[n_, m_] := p = nCr[n - 1, m] + nCr[n - 1, m - 1]
nPr[n_Integer?Positive, m_Integer?Positive] := nCr[n, m] m!
```

The Symbol `nPr` has no value (technically no `OwnValues` rule), therefore `nPr >> file` will not work.  We can however use [`Definition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Definition.html) and [`FullDefinition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullDefinition.html) in cases such as this.

```
Definition[nPr] >> "nPr-Definition.m"
```

The file shows that the line that defines `nPr` is saved, but not `nCr`:

> ```
> nPr[(n_Integer)?Positive, (m_Integer)?Positive] := nCr[n, m]*m!
> ```

By comparison, using `FullDefinition` all definition lines are saved:

```
FullDefinition[nPr] >> "nPr-FullDefinition.m"
```

> ```
> nPr[(n_Integer)?Positive, (m_Integer)?Positive] := nCr[n, m]*m!
>
> nCr[_, 0] = 1
>
> nCr[n_, n_] = 1
>
> p:nCr[n_, m_] := p = nCr[n - 1, m] + nCr[n - 1, m - 1]
> ```

Notice in these examples that the lines of code that define the functions are themselves saved, therefore loading the definition is accomplished with a simple `Get`:

```
<< "nPr-FullDefinition.m";
```

(Though undocumented, `Definition` and `FullDefinition` support multiple arguments such as `Definition[symbol1, symbol2, ...]`.  See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28936/121) for an example.)

---

### Save & DumpSave

There is an aptly named function [`Save`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Save.html) which automates that last method shown above, but with PutAppend:

> Save["filename", *symbol*]
>     appends definitions associated with the specified *symbol* to a file.
>
> - Save uses `FullDefinition` to include subsidiary definitions.

This produces contents identical to `nPr-FullDefinition.m`:

```
Save["nPr-Save.m", nPr]
```

`Save` also automates saving definitions for a list of symbols, symbol names matching a specified pattern, or all symbols in a context.  See the documentation for details.

---

To this point all files created have been in the human readable `.m` format.  [`DumpSave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DumpSave.html) diverges from this, using a platform and version specific binary `.mx` format.  This format is very fast to load, but with [rare exception](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1571/121) it should not be used for long term storage or to exchange information between users.

> DumpSave["file.mx", *symbol*]
>     writes definitions associated with a symbol to a file in internal Mathematica format.
>
> - `DumpSave` writes out definitions in a binary format that is optimized for input by Mathematica.
> - Files written by `DumpSave` can only be read on the same type of computer system on which they were written.

Another important distinction is that `DumpSave` uses `Definition` rather than `FullDefinition`.  If for some reason this behavior is needed for `Save` we can use [this trick from Janus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4094559/618728), leveraging [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Block.html):

```
Block[{FullDefinition = Definition},
  Save["filename.m", expr]
]
```

The reverse does not appear to be possible with `DumpSave` therefore one must give it a list of related symbols explicitly.

### Export

It is possible to save to and load other file formats using `Export` and `Import`.
For example, saving a GZIP compressed `.m` file directly:

```
Export["nPr-Export.m.gz", FullDefinition[nPr], {"GZIP", "Package"}]

Import["nPr-Export.m.gz"]
```

This performs worse than `Save` but the file takes considerably less space.

### Performance comparison

For testing, using the definition for `nPr` above, I call this:

```
$RecursionLimit = 15000;

nPr[3000, 150]
```

Because `nCr` uses [memoization](/questions/tagged/memoization) this creates a large number of definition rules (over 400,000).  I then test save and load speed (each done in a separate session):

```
Save["nPr-Save.m", nPr] // AbsoluteTiming

Put[FullDefinition[nPr], "nPr-FullDefinition.m"] // AbsoluteTiming

DumpSave["nPr-DumpSaveFull.mx", {nPr, nCr}] // AbsoluteTiming

Export["nPr-Export.m.gz", FullDefinition[nPr], {"GZIP", "Package"}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {13.6837827, Null}
> {9.0355168, Null}
> {14.5778338, {nPr, nCr}}
> {19.3200270, "nPr-Export.m.gz"}
> ```

Load times:

```
Get["nPr-Save.m"]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {3.4281960, Null}
> ```

```
Get["nPr-FullDefinition.m"]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {3.4361966, Null}
> ```

```
Get["nPr-DumpSaveFull.mx"]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.5560318, Null}
> ```

```
Import["nPr-Export.m.gz"]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {3.7532147, Null}
> ```

### Data versus Definitions

The examples above all relate to saving definitions, defined by `DownValues` and similar.
If one is saving an expression (data) rather than definitions `Export` is handy.

Here is a fine method from David Bailey, streamlined by Szabolcs:

```
Export["data.mc", Compress[data], "String"]

Uncompress@Import["data.mc", "String"]
```

This saves very quickly, produces a smaller file, and should be portable between systems.  It however does not load as quickly as the `"MX"` format.

If loading speed is valued at the expense of platform independence the `"MX"` format can also be used for data by using `Export`:

```
Export["data.mx", data, "MX"]
```

Or combined with compression for smaller files:

```
Export["data.mx.gz", data, {"GZIP", "MX"}]
```

Comment: Regarding the last section, it's not from me, and I actually learned it through you ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/6136838/695132

Comment: @Szabolcs I do recall that answer but I'm giving you credit because I had not seen the form with `Export`, and testing indicates that it is only marginally slower than `BinaryWrite`.  I should however also give credit to David Bailey.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard +1. I also used this technique (based on `Compress`) in a number of posts, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247005/efficiently-working-with-and-generating-large-text-files/8250860#8250860) (in a somewhat different form), and more directly, [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36/file-backed-lists-variables-for-handling-large-data/209#209). I wasn't aware of David's suggestion (missed that post of yours somehow), but he probably found this earlier than me.

Answer (score 20):

Your function, as you wrote it, *does* re-interpolate every time you call it because a [delayed definition](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html) was used.

The correct way to write it is

```
interPolFunc = Interpolation[exampleData]
```

This (as well as you example) can be saved using `Save` or `DumpSave`.

When the function is simply assigned to a variable, as I showed here, it can also be exported for example to `WDX` and re-used later:

```
Export["interpolation.wdx", interPolFunc]

interPolFunc = Import["interpolation.wdx"]
```

(Instead of WDX, or course one can use any other format that can hold arbitrary Mathematica expressions, such as the Package format with the `.m` extension or `.mx` files)

`InterpolatingFunction` objects are just like any other Mathematica expression.

When dealing with very large expressions that are slow to import/export, a good alternative to importing/exporting directly supported formats is

```
Export["data.mmaz", Compress[expression], "String"]
expression = Uncompress@Import["data.mmaz", "String"]
```

Compressed strings are quite fast to import or export and unlike MX files, they are cross-platform and cross-version compatible.  Note that MX files are not compatible between different platforms or versions of Mathematica.

Comment: Why should we use WDX rather than .m or .mx?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard We could use M or MX if you wish.  That's why I said "for example".  Any format that can hold Mathematica expressions will do. I typically use `Export["data.mmaz", Compress[data], "String"]` as the fastest compact cross-platform solution.

Comment: I am encouraging you to extend your answer.  Or I'll post.  That's a threat. ;^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard A reason I personally don't like `Save` and `DumpSave` for storing data is that the variable names are hard-coded into the file, *and* are not easy to find out what they are after import.  But this is just personal preference, so I didn't mention it in the answer.

Comment: please add the `Export["file",Compress[dat],"String"]` bit to your answer. I wrote it up for mine but luckily saw your comment before posting it.

Comment: @szablocs: Thank you for extending your answer! It has a lot of useful additional information now! I am happy to see that my question opens such an interesting discussion about Save etc.

Answer (score 16):

If you'd like to keep your function inside the notebook and not to refer to external files, there is another way. This also can come very handy for CDF files. Use `Compress` to get a string:

```
exampleData = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 7}, {5, 5}, {6, 4}, {7, 2}};
Compress[Interpolation[exampleData]]
```

Then use the string to define the function. You now need only that cell. If you restart your session and execute the cell you'll get your function back:

```
Exit

interPolFunc = Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPSmNlYGAoFgUSnnklqUUF+\
TmJJZl56W6lecklmfl5aYwgaRYg4ZNZXJLGhMzLBMllsgOJNC4UcRAjkxlEADFDHkgZCLM\
jc1hg0mhEMSeQcCwtyc8FuiMZzXp2TOuZ4HaBTQT5JpMN7i4UDaiGgbWjCTFjCrFgCrFjC\
rESpZEJQwjVtwBbEkCF"]

interPolFunc /@ RandomReal[{1, 7}, 5]
{3.52424, 4.48403, 6.00775, 4.06734, 1.50966}
```

You can hide it at the end of the document and make it run automatically by selecting it and going **Cell >> Cell Properties >> Initialization Cell**.