# Unable to operate on the table imported from .mx file

Tags: list-manipulation, import, evaluation

I saved a table by exporting it to .mx file. Now, when I import it back, it gives me the desired output.

So, to work with elements of the table, I first define the imported table as (`res2 = Import["file.mx"]`), and `res2 [[a,b,c,d]]` returns the correct output from the table in correct sequence.

However, when I try to do any kind of simple algebra with it, It simply fails, even forget all the evaluations, I did before.

For example, when I try evaluating `res2[[1,2,3,4]]+res2[[1,2,4,3]]`, Mathematica is unable to evaluate and even forget all the previous evaluations. What to do? I want to work with elements in the table of my file.mx. Otherwise what is the point of saving such huge collection of data?

Is there any alternative way, please tell me. It takes days to create the table. Now, I have the table saved in .mx file, but I am unable to do any algebra with elements. How to define a variable for the elements and work with it?

Comment: It is quite unclear to me how the data looks. Sounds as if it were symbolic... In order to narrow down what goes wrong: Have you tried to do the export and import with a somewhat smaller dataset? It would be great if you could provide a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get`:

```
Get["file-name.mx"];
```

If the table was called `res2` When it was saved, then you should now have a symbol by the same name. You can now do

```
res2[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

as before.

Comment: I saved it using ( Export["file-name.mx",res2]; ), Get is also not working, It doesn't even know what is res2.

Comment: Save it using `DumpSave`.

Comment: I have to run it again I guess for that. Can I import, define and dump-save again? i.e. ( res2 = Import ["file-name.mx"]) and then dumpsave res2? as that command is at least giving me correct values when I evaluate let's say res2 [[1,2,3,4]]. It just doesn't allow doing any algebra on it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to do that. MX is a binary format, and `DumpSave` is built to handle it correctly.

Comment: I ll have to run it again, there is one very good method of writing and reading the table element wise, I will use that from next time..I just followed this advice before https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51460/67076 but apparently it doesn't work properly, that answer is incomplete..

Comment: @Tripsy , I would present a small example for others to test it.