# exporting list of matrices in mathematica

Tags: matrix, export

I am working on some problem which requires generating a list of random matrices. So I used the code (actually a shortened version of the code, but it does not matter)

```
L={};
For[n = 1, n <= 10, n++,
 R = RandomComplex[{-1 - 1 I, 1 + 1 I}, {2,2}];
ApppendTo[L,R]
]
Export["list.dat",L]
```

So far so good, but when I try to import them by

```
Import["list.dat"]
```

it imports the list but pus a ',' after each and every string. In particular, after each +, -, I, }, and after each ',' as well! Some variations (like importing as table and so on) are not giving anything better. I tried to export it as .mat format which gives the following error

```
Export::type: {{{-0.0542175+0.284324 I,-<<21>>-<<19>> I},{<<1>>}},<<9>>} cannot be exported to the MAT format. >>
```

I am using mathematica 6 and 7 both.

Advanced thanks for any hint/ suggestions.

Comment: Do you plan to import these in any other program than Mathematica itself?

Comment: @Szabolcs no. i am at present working only on mathematica. i want to generate a huge list first, save it separately and then import the list to pick up matrices and do different works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, if you're a beginner, it's best to try to avoid `For` loops as much as possible.  In most cases there are better ways to do thing.  `AppendTo` in particular is quite slow because it reallocates the array on  every append.

So use

```
data = Table[
 RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, {2, 2}],
 {10}
 ]
```

or even simpler:

```
data = RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, {10, 2, 2}]
```

As for exporting and importing, it's best to specify the format explicitly.  Since you only plan to import the data to Mathematica, I suggest using a format that can store arbitrary expressions.  There are four basic choices:

- The WDX format, also used for example data
- The MX format which is extremely quick to read/write but is neither cross-platform, nor cross architecture
- The `"Package"` format which will just write the Mathematica expressions as strings
- [Using `Compress` and exporting as a string.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1960/12)

I recommend you use WDX if the data is not large and performance is not critical.  For best performance, use MX, but be aware that the files will not be portable to other computers.  For good performance and portability, use the `Compress` trick.

```
Export["data.wdx", data, "WDX"]

data = Import["data.wdx"]
```

Comment: I'm using `Export["data.mx.gz",data]` which I think is a good compromise between files size and the speed of loading.

Comment: @Ajasja The main point of `Compress` is not to reduce the file size here.  It is to make the file portable.  `.mx.gz` is still not portable between computers.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I had 100 MB mx files laying around, and just adding ".gz" reduced the file size 3-4 times, while not noticeably hindering the speed of loading.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for the reply and it worked. i have written above a simplified version of the code. actually there are a few more things which i have put under 'For' loop. nevertheless, can you please tell me why you advice using 'For' loop judiciously?

Comment: @rsg `For` loops have their place; but in the *vast* majority of cases there are better ways to solve a problem than using a `For` loop. If you're a beginner, I recommend you try to avoid them as much as possible: this'll improve your code.  If you need to stick to a procedural style, you can almost always use `Do` in place of `For`: `Do` is more readable for people used to Mathematica (`For` is not too nice in Mma as you might have noticed), and `Do` localized its variable, eliminating one potential source of error.  For long procedural loops,  `Reap`/`Sow` will be much faster than `AppendTo`

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks a lot. rewriting the code. the runtime was a real concern for me to generate a long list of matrices with a few properties which were time consuming.