# Problems with DumpSave and memoization

Tags: memoization

I defined a function that takes some time to compute using memoization:

```
y[a_, b_, c_] := y[a, b, c] = First[$y /. NDSolve[.........]
```

so that if I call y[a,b,c] a second time it doesn't do the `NDSolve` computation all over again if it has already done it.

How can I save the result of this to file? I tried `DumpSave["test.mx", y[3/10, 2, 0]]` after calling `y[3/10, 2, 0]` (i.e. it is now an `InterpolatingFunction`; the result of `NDSolve`), but I get the error

```
"DumpSave::bsnosym: y[3/10,2,0] is not defined as a symbol or a context. >>"
```

If I call `y[3/10,2,0][2]` etc I get the correct numeric result.

Is there some reason this is not working?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.se! I've formatted your code to make it more readable. For inline code, wrap the code in grave marks ``. For code blocks, indent each line by 4 spaces.

Comment: I merged your registered and unregistered accounts so that you now have all questions and answers and the corresponding rep in one, registered account. You should be able to comment now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is that `DumpSave` expects a *symbol* as the second argument. The doc page says:

> **DumpSave["file.mx",symbol]** writes definitions associated with a symbol
>   to a file in internal Mathematica format.

With

```
ClearAll[y]
y[a_, b_, c_] := y[a, b, c] =  NDSolve[{y''[x] == a x, y[0] == b, y'[0] == c}, y[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

and

```
y[3/10, 2, 0]
```

> {{y[x] -> InterpolatingFunction[][x]}}

you can see that y is a symbol

```
y // Head
```

> Symbol

whereas `y[3/10, 2, 0]` is not:

```
 y[3/10, 2, 0] // Head
```

> List

It is the *expression* `{{y[x] -> InterpolatingFunction[][x]}}` as we have seen above.

To save expressions, such as a single instantiations of your memoized function, you can use `Put` (`>>`).

```
y[3/10, 2, 0] >> "test.mx"

Clear[y]
<<"test.mx"
```

> {{y[x] -> InterpolatingFunction[][x]}}

To save the whole of `y`, basic definition and all memoized versions, you can `DumpSave` y itself:

```
DumpSave["test.mx", y];
Clear[y]
<<"test.mx"
?y
```

> y[3/10,2,0]={{y[x]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},{4,23,2,{27},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic},{{0.,0.0002208643237,<<...>>,9.481521054,10.}},{Developer`PackedArrayForm,{0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81},{2.,<<...>>,3.}},{Automatic}][x]}}
>
> y[a_,b_,c_]:=y[a,b,c]=NDSolve[{(y^[Prime][Prime])[x]==a x,y[0]==b,(y^[Prime])[0]==c},y[x],{x,0,10}]

An extensive treatment of all ways to save data for posterity can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2008/57).

---

**EDIT**

To conveniently select a specific memoized definition you could use the following:

```
dumpSaveSelect[y_] :=
 DynamicModule[{sol, file},
  Manipulate[
   (DownValues[y][[i, 1]]) /. 
    HoldPattern -> HoldForm, {{i, 1, "DownValue:"}, 1, 
    Length[DownValues[y]], 1, ControlType -> SetterBar},
   Button["DumpSave",
    sol = DownValues[y][[i, 1]];
    file = SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "myfile.mx"];
    DumpSave[file, sol],
    Method -> "Queued"
    ],
   ControlPlacement -> {Top, Bottom}
   ]
  ]

dumpSaveSelect[y]
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for the useful answers, but I don't want to dump the whole of 'y' really (since y will be growing as I compute the interpfuncs for more and more params. Unless there is a way to just append the bits of y that have not yet been written to file?). Is it not poss to just dump a y[1,2,3] for certain params?

Comment: @fpghost If you examine my answer closely, you'll see a discussion of `Put` that just does that.

Comment: I am aware I can use "put" as you suggested, but surely then I lose the economy of DumpSave? (the normal saving of my interp funcs outputs ~200MB files you see). I'd like to save them in this compressed format.

Comment: @fpghost, you should register so that you are able to comment on answers to your questions...

Comment: @fpghost In that case, just assign `y[3/10, 2, 0]` to a variable and `DumpSave` that. This is basically what [Bill Simpson](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8873/57) does. Or, you might consider using `Compress`.

Comment: @fpghost See also last edit

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following

```
In[1]:= sol=NDSolve[{y′[x]==y[x],y[1] == 2},y,{x, 0, 3}][[1, 1]]

Out[1]= y->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,3.}},<>]

In[2]:= DumpSave["nds.mx",sol]

Out[2]= {y->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,3.}},<>]}
```

Exit Mathematica

Start Mathematica, and run this

```
In[1]:= Get["nds.mx"] (* or use two < and no quotes and nds.mx *)

In[2]:= y[1]/.sol

Out[2]= 2.
```

Comment: I formatted your code, as it was difficult to follow as it was. Plus I added a bit of explanatory text to improve the flow of the answer.