# How to store a SparseArray?

Tags: sparse-arrays

How to Export/Write a SparseArray?
How to Import/Read a SparseArray?
Is it always stored as a normal array?
How can it be stored in a dense form?
Is a numerical SparseArray different to
Export/Import from a string one?

Comment: What a nice poem

Comment: You can use the methods described in answer to this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1959/121 In fact I am inclined to close this question as I believe it has already been answered.

Answer (score 5):

The two file formats I am familiar with, with respect to sparse matrices, are the [Harwell-Boeing format](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/HarwellBoeing.html), and the [Matrix Market format](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/MTX.html). I have linked to the docs on how you can `Import[]`/`Export[]` matrices in those formats, and you'll do well by reading up on them.

Sparse arrays are very much different from lists. For instance, consider these two representations of the $9\times 9$ identity matrix:

```
idDense = IdentityMatrix[9];
idSparse = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, {9, 9}];
```

For the purposes of `Equal[]`, they're the same:

```
idSparse == idDense
   True
```

`SameQ[]` shows that they aren't:

```
idSparse === idDense
   False
```

One can peek at heads to see the difference:

```
Head /@ {idSparse, idDense}
   {SparseArray, List}
```

If, for some reason, you need to convert your sparse array to a dense array, that's what `Normal[]` is for:

```
Normal[idSparse] === idDense
   True
```

See the docs for `SparseArray[]` and `Normal[]` for more details.

Comment: OK.   .   .What if you have txt char data instead?   .   .As in your example idSparse above replace the 1 by "A"?   .   .It is still a SparseArry.   .   .How to export this one?   .   .Can't see it in Harwell-Boeing or Matrix Market.

Comment: I don't believe any of those formats will work for data with text entries. You will have to use `Normal[]` on your sparse array and then export to your favorite format.