# How can I export definitions of several symbols to a single file?

Tags: export, data

the problem [related to this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/how-do-i-save-a-variable-or-function-definition-to-a-file/1960#1960)

What I want to do is to `Export` definition of several symbol into a single file. The reason I choose `Export` is that `Export` supports the `GZIP` function.

So here is the example: 
I have

```
ff[1, 1] = 1;
ff[1, 2] = 2;
gg[1, 1] = 3;
gg[1, 2] = 4;
```

if I use `Save`, then it is simply

```
Save["ffgg.m", {ff, gg}]
```

the content of `ffgg.m` file

```
ff[1, 1] = 1
ff[1, 2] = 2
gg[1, 1] = 3
gg[1, 2] = 4
```

But if I want to `Export`, since the syntax of `Export` is `Export["file", expr]`. It seems that I can only `Export` one `expr` each time. I tried the following code:

```
Export["ffgg2.m", {FullDefinition @ ff, FullDefinition @ gg}];
```

the content of `ffgg2.m` will be

```
(* Created by Wolfram Mathematica 8.0 : www.wolfram.com *)
{ff[1, 1] = 1
ff[1, 2] = 2, gg[1, 1] = 3
gg[1, 2] = 4}
```

And if I Import `ffgg2.m` back, I only get `ff[1,1]` and `gg[1,1]`. The other two lost.

**So how can I `Export` several definitions into a single file at a single time?**

Comment: matheorem, my code in the `PutAppend` section was broken on Symbols with `OwnValues` assignments; my attempt to keep these unevaluated was poorly conceived.  I believe I have corrected the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### `FullDefinition`

You can use the undocumented(?) multi-argument syntax of `FullDefinition`:

```
ExportString[FullDefinition[ff, gg], "Package"]
```

> ```
> (* Created by Wolfram Mathematica 7.0 : www.wolfram.com *)
>
> ff[1, 1] = 1
>
> ff[1, 2] = 2
>
> gg[1, 1] = 3
>
> gg[1, 2] = 4
> ```

You will notice that any arguments of `FullDefinition` after the first will be colored, by default in red.  This usually [signifies a syntax error](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/WarningsAndMessages.html), but more specifically here it means the syntax doesn't match the pattern given in [`SyntaxInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SyntaxInformation.html).  There are a number of functions that work with syntax somewhat different form that which is officially supported (documented).  Of course such functionality may change or be removed in later versions so you have to weigh the alternatives.  If you are comfortable with this caveat you can eliminate the red highlighting with:

```
Unprotect[FullDefinition]

SyntaxInformation[FullDefinition] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {__}}

Protect[FullDefinition]
```

---

The OP asked:

> I searched some questions relate Undocumented functions. Many people suggest "don't use it". So is there any other way to realize the same thing?

Yes, but none that I know of that is as concise.

### `PutAppend`

You can use `PutAppend` to append definitions to a file:

```
Cases[Hold[ff, gg], x_ :> (FullDefinition@x >>> "file.m")];
```

> ```
> (* contents of file *)
> ff[1, 1] = 1
>
> ff[1, 2] = 2
> gg[1, 1] = 3
>
> gg[1, 2] = 4
> ```

This uses multiple "export" (or rather `PutAppend`) commands, but it seems to do what you want.

Even more manually you can `ExportString` each definition then concatenate them:

```
strings = Cases[Hold[ff, gg], x_ :> ExportString[FullDefinition@x, "Package"]];

Export["file.m", StringJoin @ strings, "Text"]  (* note "Text" format *)
```

Comment: WoW, "FullDefinition[ff,gg]"! I tried this before, But I found that the second argument of `FullDefinition` is Red, So I give up. But I encourage to try it a second time. `Export["ffgg3.m",FullDefinition[ff,gg]]`, though the `gg` argument is red, but it works! Can you tell me why this red is safe and works? What does this red mean? why this is undocumented? where did you know about this?

Comment: Well, I searched some questions relate `Undocumented functions`. Many people suggest "don't use it". So is there any other way to realize the same thing?

Comment: @matheorem I added a couple of alternatives.  Since you didn't explain exactly why you are using `Export` I'm having to guess as to your needs and I hope that `PutAppend` will serve.