# Save[] but without duplicate data?

Tags: save

I wanna be able to start my session by loading a bunch of data and then finish by saving everything.

Here's an example of what I've been doing: I have the function `g[x_] := g[x] = x^2`, I calculate `g[1]` and `g[2]`, and I run `Save["data.m", {g}]`. Next session I load with `Get["data.m"]`, and then I calculate `g[3]` and `g[4]` and save, intending to get a file with `g[x_]` as well as `g[1]` through `g[4]`.

But as it turns out, `Save` appends rather than overwrites, and it doesn't just append the new stuff. So it'll contain `g[1]`, `g[2]`, `g[x_]`, `g[1]`, `g[2]`, `g[3]`, `g[4]`, `g[x_]`.

What's the best approach here? Should I just overwrite the file when I save, and if so, is there a better way than `DeleteFile["data.m"]`? Is there a way to append but only the new stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "Is there a way to append but only the new stuff?"

No, not that I know of. Of course you could save *to a new file*. The new file should contain both the new and old definitions, without replication.

- "Should I just overwrite the file when I save?"

You can, since the contents of the file have been loaded in memory and will be saved out again. But it may be safer to `Save` *to a new file* in case something goes wrong, particularly if calculation of each value is time-consuming. Devise a tagging method (e.g. programmatically use the current date and time in the file name, see e.g. [`CurrentDate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentDate.html))

- "Is there a better way than `DeleteFile["data.m"]`?"

You could call an OS specific command, but `DeleteFile` is pretty convenient...

See also:

- [How can I export definitions of several symbols to a single file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28935/27951)
- [How do I save a variable or function definition to a file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1959/27951)