# How to export a table of complex numbers?

Tags: export, import, complex, list-manipulation

I'm having problems exporting a table of complex numbers. I have:

```
tablevalues=Table[M[a,b],{b,1,101},{a,-500+5*(b-1),500+5*(b-1),5}];
Export["trial.dat",tablevalues,"Table"];
```

But then when I try to import the data using:

```
Data=Import["trial.dat","Table"];
```

I find that the `Table` has changed (later commands in my code no longer work, despite the fact that they do work if I use `tablevalues` directly).

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

More info: the code for M is:

```
M[a_, b_] := l1[a, b] + l2[a, b] -l3[a, b];
```

where `l1`, `l2` and `l3` are calculated for different a and b (the full expressions are quite long).

Comment: Could you also provide the code vor the symbol `M`?

Comment: I cannot find .dat in the list of possible export formats: [http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$ExportFormats.html](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$ExportFormats.html). It works fine when using Mathematica .mx for example.

Comment: @g3kk0 I've tried with .mx but it still doesn't work?

Comment: @g3kk0 ah, leaving out the "Table" with .mx does seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: For a readable version of your data you can also use something like `Export["trial.dat",tablevalues,"Package"]` or simply `Export["trial.m",tablevalues]`. Importing is then easy, especially with Get. Seems slower than `.mx `though, but uses less space.

Comment: Or for another flavor: `Export["trial.m.gz", tablevalues]` and Import["trial.m.gz"] which seems both faster and more economic storagewise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the .dat format you should have a look at the tutorial http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingData.html.

**Workaround 1**

You can use *Mathematica*'s .mx format to export and then import your data. You can have a look at the format description at http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/MX.html.

```
M[a_, b_] := l1[a, b] + l2[a, b] - l3[a, b];
tablevalues = 
 Table[M[a, b], {b, 1, 101}, {a, -500 + 5*(b - 1), 500 + 5*(b - 1), 
   5}]; Export["trial.mx", tablevalues];

data = Import["trial.mx"];
data[[1, 1 ;; 5]]
(*{l1[-500, 1] + l2[-500, 1] - l3[-500, 1], 
 l1[-495, 1] + l2[-495, 1] - l3[-495, 1], 
 l1[-490, 1] + l2[-490, 1] - l3[-490, 1], 
 l1[-485, 1] + l2[-485, 1] - l3[-485, 1], 
 l1[-480, 1] + l2[-480, 1] - l3[-480, 1]}*)
```

**Workaround 2**

As [Yves Klett](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/131/yves-klett) pointed out, another nice workaround is  to use:

```
Export["trial.m",tablevalues]
```

to store your data in a *Mathematica* package. Importing is then easy, especially with the `Get` function:

```
<<"trial.m"
```

Answer (score 4):

After playing around a bit, I am surprised to find that this seems to be faster and uses *far* less diskspace than the `.mx` approach:

```
Export["trial.mx", tablevalues] // AbsoluteTiming
FileByteCount[%[[2]]]

(* {3.347335, "trial.mx"} *)
(* 7970752 *)

Export["trial.m.gz", tablevalues] // AbsoluteTiming
FileByteCount[%[[2]]]

(* {0.401040, "trial.m.gz"} *)
(* 140508 *)

data = Import["trial.m.gz"];
data[[1, 1 ;; 5]]

(* {l1[-500, 1] + l2[-500, 1] - l3[-500, 1], 
 l1[-495, 1] + l2[-495, 1] - l3[-495, 1], 
 l1[-490, 1] + l2[-490, 1] - l3[-490, 1], 
 l1[-485, 1] + l2[-485, 1] - l3[-485, 1], 
 l1[-480, 1] + l2[-480, 1] - l3[-480, 1]} *)
```

Comment: FWIW I mentioned this format [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2008/121) but I did not realize you could use the extension `.m.gz` directly without specifying the format. +1!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard interesting how the timings differ depending on content. Would you consider the question a duplicate, then?

Comment: No, I think it's reasonable to have a more focused question in this case.  That post made no specific mention of complex numbers.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Another thing is the timing - the `.m` takes forever and you can watch it being written incrementally on disk while the `.gz` really saves the day. Was not aware of that - might come in handy.

Comment: I know that this is an old question but I just had the same issue. The answer of @g3kk0 is perfect using the mx trick, however, sometimes we need the data in a dat format for processing. Therefore, I think that by exporting the data as a real numbers and then importing and converting to complex also may be usefull.