# Save associations to a file and reload

Tags: associations, persistence

I have many (say 2 for now) associations that I want to save to a file

```
<|"A" -> 1 , "B" -> 2|> >>> NotebookDirectory[] <> "TEST.m"
<|"A" -> 11 , "B" -> 22|> >>> NotebookDirectory[] <> "TEST.m"
```

Now I would like to somehow get all this expressions into a list, obtaining

```
{<|"A" -> 1 , "B" -> 2|>,<|"A" -> 11 , "B" -> 22|>}
```

But if I do

```
loaded = Get[NotebookDirectory[] <> "TEST.m"]
```

I obtain only the last one

```
<|"A" -> 11 , "B" -> 22|>
```

What is the correct thing to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your file does contain the expressions you saved but [`Get`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Get.html) *evaluates* the file rather than importing the lines as expressions.  The latter can be done with [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Import.html):

```
Import["TEST.m", "ExpressionList"]
```

> ```
> {<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2|>, <|"A" -> 11, "B" -> 22|>}
> ```

Alternatively you could also save a definition rather than the bare expressions.  See:

- [How do I save a variable or function definition to a file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1959/121)

---

As [Albert Retey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/169/albert-retey) comments I failed to mention that the behavior in this case is not related to `Association` but only the mechanics of `PutAppend` and especially `Get`.  The same behavior would be seen for any series of standard expressions.

An additional note: the `Import` command above evaluates expressions (like `Get`) but also returns a list of them.  If you wish to *only* return a list without evaluating at all you can use:

```
Import["file.m", "HeldExpressions"]
```

Each expression will be returned wrapped in [`HoldComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldComplete.html).

These `Import` elements are described in the documentation for the [Package format](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Package.html).

Comment: thanks, that's very useful, wouldn't hav had `"ExpressionList"` on my mind. You might want to add that that problem hasn't anything to do with the fact that the OP is saving associations, he'd have had the very same problem with `PutAppend` lists or even just numbers...

Comment: @Albert I added what you suggested to my answer.  I also added a link to the page where these formats are documented.

Answer (score 5):

The by far fastest method to store and retrieve any data in Mathematica is to use the .mx format:

```
asso = {<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2|>, <|"A" -> 11, "B" -> 22|>};
Export["myasso.mx", asso]
```

The really great news about .mx is that, contrary to [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MX.html) 10.0 documentation, you can since Mathematica 10.0 exchange them between different operating systems, i.e. if you read the above file in under e.g. Linux by `Import["myasso.mx"]` you get back `{<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2|>, <|"A" -> 11, "B" -> 22|>}`

Comment: I'm giving a +1 for this for continued dissemination of important information, however I do not believe this is applicable to the OP's needs as I believe he needs incremental output, i.e. `PutAppend`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am no friend of `PutAppend`. People should use Reap / Sow . Even if the list of associations grows larger than available RAM, I would (and once did) construct large sub-lists being saved as .mx files. So much faster than anything else.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you are correct, my input is incremental. rolf-mertig interesting approach with reap+saw+mx. I will think about that for larger dataset.

Comment: @Rolf Mertig: I cannot agree more with you about `.mx` file import/export speed. It is extremely fast compared to `csv, xls, dat` formats.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve put the associations in a Dataset and saved it via:

```
exp = Export["file.m", dataset]
```

Reading the data in is done via

```
dataset = Import["file"]
```

this works without problems, also for associations (without converting to a Dataset).

Comment: But I don't know in advance how many I will have. I am generating them and putting into a file