# Using Get function to return a specific expression

Tags: functions, import, formatting

I am trying to use `Get`to import data saved as a .nb document. The problem is `Get`evaluates all expressions but only returns the last one. 
How can I return other expressions from the document?

---

e.g.

```
A={1,2,3,4,5};
B=A^2;
C=Mean[B];
Save["test",{A,B,C}];

Get["test"]
```

The output is 11, but I also want `B` to be listed in the output.

---

I am not able to rearrange the .nb document as it would require rerunning the code (takes several days), or manually changing the data (very tedious with~5GB worth of data). 
Are there any alternative functions I might be able to use?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The values of b, etc. will be set, so they're available for use. Frankly, this seems like a bit of a bizarre way to do something. In addition, don't use uppercase initials for your symbols - it can clash with built-ins (I'm surprised you don't report an error with `C` - that's protected...)

Comment: Related: [(60734)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60734/121)

Comment: With the uppercase initials I was just trying to create a simple example of the problem I have. I understand the values of b are available, however my actual data is importing several documents that use the same expression names. If I import using Get only the data (ie. b) from the last document is available.

Comment: I came up with this and it seems to work; `Table[Get["test"<>ToSting[i]<>".nb"]; B, {i,1,rep}]`. Where `rep` is the number of replicate runs.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly you want the [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) format `"HeldExpressions"`:

```
Import["test", "HeldExpressions"]
```

> ```
> {HoldComplete[A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}],
>  HoldComplete[B = {1, 4, 9, 16, 25}], 
>  HoldComplete[Attributes[C] = {NHoldAll, Protected}]}
> ```

The last expression may not be as you expect until you remember that [`C`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/C.html) is a reserved System Symbol.

---

Sorry, I overlooked the fact that you said you had a `.nb` file as your first example is a different format.  Instead of `Import` please look at [`NotebookImport`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookImport.html) and try a command like:

```
NotebookImport[NotebookOpen @ "file.nb"]
```

It has a number of configuration options; please try a few of them.  If you have trouble getting what you want let me know.

Comment: Import seems to be the way to go, I just don't know which format to use to return the data in a way it can be expressed. The Import can only use the formats {Data, Lines, Plaintext, String, Words} with a .nb document.

Comment: @JamesReeve updated.

Comment: Thanks that should work, I just can't use the NotebookImport function on my version of Mathematica, even though I am using Mathematica 10 for Mac OS.

Comment: @JamesReeve Perhaps it was only introduced in 10.1? I'll try to think of another solution.