# Mathematica: issues storing nested list on disk

Tags: export, import

having trouble with mathematica using nested lists. I want to save a list like this:

```
l1={{a1,{a,b,c,d,e}},{a2,{f,g,h,i}}}
```

So, the nested components do not have an identical dimension. However, whenever I save the file (as csv or xls) and reimport it seems that the inner lists (like l1[[1,2]] is transformed into a string which I would like to bypass somehow.

Comment: If your aim is to re-import into Mathematica, use a format that can store arbitrary Mathematica expressions.  This includes the `"WDX"`, `"Package"` and `"MX"` `Export` formats.  Some prefer using `Compress` and exporting the result as a `"String"`.  Note that `"MX"` is not cross-version-compatible and not cross platform before v10.

Comment: Related: [(2008)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2008/121)

Comment: ["CSV stores tabular data."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)  More specifically, it stores ragged-right 2D arrays.  XLS stores a set of sparse 2D arrays and some metadata.  They are simply not capable of encoding nested lists of arbitrary depth.

Comment: thanks a lot for the clarification with the *.csv and *.xls-files. The MX-package works fine, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having

`l1 = {{a1, {a, b, c, d, e}}, {a2, {f, g, h, i}}};`

one exports using

`Put[l1,"out.dat"]`

and imports next with

`Get["out.dat"]`

If you don't `SetDirectory`, it will go to home directory and be then imported from there also.

---

See also [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131853/22013).

Comment: Does that really resolve the issue here? Essentially, I am not able to access the parts of my nested lists because some are simply converted to a string?

Comment: I updated the answer providing a working example.