# Exporting, Importing and plotting LIsts

Tags: list-manipulation, import

I have two lists,

```
data = {{1000,800}, {1500,3300}}
```

and

```
data1 = {{0,0}, {1,0}}
```

I combined them and exporter them:

```
Export["...path", {data, data1}, "List"]
```

In a different file, I import it:

```
datar = Import["...path", "List"]
```

Of which d1 = datar[[1]] seems to be a list, but when I plot

```
ListPlot[d1]
```

it says that it's not " a list of numbers or pairs of numbers.

Comment: `Export` with `"List"` means exporting a 1D array; with `"Table"` you could `Export` a matrix. For more complicated `List`s, see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79855/22013).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CSV and To Expression to convert to numeric format

```
data = {{1000, 800}, {1500, 3300}}
data1 = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}
Export["jose", {data, data1}, "CSV"]
datar = Import["jose", "CSV"]
d1 = ToExpression[datar[[1]]]
ListPlot[d1]
```

[image]