# Import from CSV formatting issue

Tags: csv-format

I have two lists of data here: dm and dmHalo (see attached image). Theses are the same lists, the only difference is that dm was exported to a csv file and then reimported, while dmHalo was generated in the notebook session.

When I go to run an interpolation on the data set the interpolation does not recognize the csv imported data, as seen in the error message. I assume this is due to a change in formatting, but I am at a loss at how to revert to the native format.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Thanks you for your help!

[image]

Comment: Have you check with Dimensions[] that both object have the same dimensions?

Comment: And `Head /@ {dm, dmHalo}`

Comment: Try `First[dm] // InputForm` and if there are quotes (`"`) around the numbers, you've imported text instead of numbers. How did you export and import to CSV (`Export` and `Import`)? Please show the code you used.

Comment: @Drod Thank you for your suggestion. Yes Dimension returns {} for dm and {30,2} for dmHalo.

Comment: @Rohit This returns String and List.

Comment: @creidhne :
`halo38 = Import["row_data/avgTables_halo38.csv"];
dm = halo38[[5]][[2]]`
I used this. I now realize dm is imported as a string and not as a list. 

Is there a way to import as a List? I've tried importing with the keywords "Data", "Table", and "List" and nothing has worked. 

Thank you all!

Comment: I also used the following code to export:

`Export[{"row_data/avgTables_halo1.csv"}, halo1]`

Without adding "List" to the specifications so I'm not sure if I an recover the format in an easy way.

Comment: I just tested exporting the data with `Export["row_data/testHalo.csv", dmHalo, "Data"]` and it imported as a List. My problem now is that I have a large set of data that would take a long time to regenerate in the right format. Is there a way to salvage all of the data I have saved as strings?

Comment: EDIT: It seems that the "Data" specifier did not work because when I access the nested list it is still a String and not a List. I have tried using .dat and .txt and none work. It seems to be a problem with the format of my lists themselves, since they are in the format: {{ 1 ,{ {}...{} , {}...{} }}}. I think this format isnt easily understood by the different formats...

Comment: @asorlik Try `ToExpression @ dm`.

Comment: Thanks all for commenting. You help was invaluable!

Answer (score 1):

The nested lists are saved as strings so `ToExpression` has to be mapped.

```
data = {{1, {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, {8, 9}}}, 10, {11, 12}}};

export = ExportString[data, "CSV"];
import = ImportString[export, "CSV"];

importData = import // Map[ToExpression]
importData == data
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Summary of issue: dmHalo and dm in the original post were inner parts of a nested data structure in the format `{{i, {{j,k,l},{m,n,o},{...}}}}`. The problem is that the export formats--.csv, .dat, .txt.-- regardless of keyword--"Data","Table","List"--would convert the inner lists into strings in a way that is irreversible (at least from what I have tried i.e. using ToExpression on the resulting string).

SOLUTION: Using Put and Get ([Mathematica: issues storing nested list on disk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79854/mathematica-issues-storing-nested-list-on-disk)) has seemed to resolve the issue and I now can recover the list format of the inner nested lists. As seen in the images, the export process converts the inner list to a string, whereas with the Put and Get commands the list format is preserved.

[image]

[image]