# Saving and loading lists of interpolating functions fast and cross-platform

Tags: differential-equations, export, import, interpolation, save

Is there any way to save and load several lists of interpolating functions efficiently and cross-platform?

I want to save the resulting interpolating functions of NDSolve which takes very long to generate so next time I can just load the same result into Mathematica.
The following is an example of lists of long interpolating functions:

```
s1 = Table[
    NDSolve[{f''[x] == -k f[x], f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0}, f, {x, 0, 100000}][[1]],
    {k, 1, 10}
  ];
fl1 = f /. s1; (* 1st list of functions *)
s2 = Table[
    NDSolve[{f''[x] == -k f[x], f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 1}, f, {x, 0, 100000}][[1]],
    {k, 1, 10}
  ];
fl2 = f /. s2; (* 2nd list of functions *)
```

The sizes of them are `ByteCount[{fl1, fl2}]` 1,363,723,536 Bytes (about 1.3 GB) in memory.

The fastest way I know is to `DumpSave` them using

```
DumpSave["data.mx", {fl1, fl2}];
```

This only takes a few seconds. The file size is also about 1.3 GB.

Loading them back also takes a few second:

```
Quit[]
Get["data.mx"]
```

However, `DumpSave` is not cross-platform. The saved `.mx` file can't be read by other computers with different architectures/system. (At least, it doesn't work between Mathematica 10.2 and 10.4.)

I have tried using `Save`:

```
Save["data2.mx", {fl1, fl2}]
```

but this is too slow and computationally intensive. The file size also appears to be much bigger.

So is there other ways to save & load interpolating functions with efficiency similar to `DumpSave`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I was writing my question, I found a solution. I can use `Export` and `Import`.

```
Export["data3.mx", {fl1, fl2}, "MX"] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {13.1173, "data3.mx"} *)
```

which takes few second longer than `DumpSave` but with the same file size (1.3 GB). I can then `Import` them by

```
{fl1, fl2} = Import["data3.mx"];
```

(See also the last section of [How do I save a variable or function definition to a file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/how-do-i-save-a-variable-or-function-definition-to-a-file/2008#2008))

The slight issue is that you need to know the order of each symbol and their names when you import them.

Also, using `Get["data3.mx"]` won't work in this case. Not sure why.

It will be helpful if someone know a way to save/load several lists of interpolating functions efficiently but without knowing their names while loading them.