# A glitch with importing a list of lists of polynomials

Tags: import, string-manipulation

Would anybody know how to import a list of lists of polynomials which I exported earlier?

```
d = {{3*t^2 + 2*t^(-1), 5*t + 6*t^(-2) + 7*t^(-4)}, {7*t^2 + 8*t^(-1), 9*t + 10*t^(-2)}} 
Export["mydata.dat",d] 
Import["mydata.dat"] 
Out[]={{"2/t", "+", "3*t^2", "7/t^4", "+", "6/t^2", "+", "5*t"}, {"8/t", "+", "7*t^2", "10/t^2", "+", "9*t"}}

imp=Import["mydata.dat", "List"]
Out[]={2/t + 3*t^2  7/t^4 + 6/t^2 + 5*t, 8/t + 7*t^2    10/t^2 + 9*t}
imp[[1]]
Out[]= 2/t + 3*t^2  7/t^4 + 6/t^2 + 5*t
imp[[1]][[1]] 
error: Part::partd: Part specification 2/t + 3*t^2  7/t^4 + 6/t^2 + 5*t[[1]] is longer than depth of object.
Head @ imp[[1]]
Out[]=String
```

Exporting as "List" does not help.

EDIT: Dominic's solution of using .mx does the job. However, it uses Mathematica's internal (obscure) format and that does not work for me. I need an understandable data format, so that I can generate my own data in that format.

Comment: Depending on your ultimate goal, you might want to use `Put` and `Get`.  For example, `d >> "mydata.dat"` to write the file and `g = Get["mydata.dat"]` to read it.

Comment: You may want to look at the answers to [How do I save a ... definition to a file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/how-do-i-save-a-variable-or-function-definition-to-a-file)

Comment: Try using the ".mx" extension:  d2 = {{3*t^2 + 2*t^(-1), 
   5*t + 6*t^(-2) + 7*t^(-4)}, {7*t^2 + 8*t^(-1), 9*t + 10*t^(-2)}}
Export["mydata.mx", d2]
newd = Import["mydata.mx"]

Comment: @LouisB: Thanks Louis, your simple solution fixed the problem.