# How to download and keep a dictionary?

Tags: memory, dictionary

I use a Dictionary and download it by the command (example Swedish):

dict1 = DictionaryLookup[{"Swedish",
Repeated[{alfabetet}, {1, Infinity}]}]

It downloads and all is well.

But when I switch off the computer everything goes and I have to download it again next time.

The question is how to download and keep it locally, is this possible at all?
I am on a Raspberry Pi and could possible have it on a memory card.
Thank you in advance for any pointers!

Comment: What is `alfabetet`? Please explore the `DumpSave` command.

Comment: How is this any different from writing `x=10` in a notebook and then shutting down the computer. When you  start you PC again, `x` will have no value and you need to evaluate `x=10` to give `x` its old value back. If you want to save some variables to a file, see [how-do-i-save-a-variable-or-function-definition-to-a-file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/how-do-i-save-a-variable-or-function-definition-to-a-file)

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I will try the suggestions as soon as possible. will be back tomorrow.