# Problems with 'DumpSave' and 'Save' in Mathematica 13.1 on Windows 11

Tags: expression-manipulation, files-and-directories, save

My  Mathematica 13.1 crashes when I  try to see the result of 'Save' for some very long expressions, and produces short DumpSave files which when clicked on contain only Null.

I have a system

```
    L = \[Lambda] - mx  x; fz = y (bc/(kb + y) - dc/(kd + y)) - mz;
    x1 = L -   \[Beta] x v ;
    y1 = \[Beta] x v  - byz y z - my  y;
    v1 = B my y - \[Beta] x v - bvz  v z - mv  v;
    z1 = z fz;
    dyn = {x1, y1, v1, z1}; X = {x, y, v, z};
    cfp = Solve[Thread[dyn == 0], X]
    Length[cfp]
    cfp[[1]]
cfp[[2]]
```

This takes a little while to solve on Mathematica and yields 6 answers, the first and second ones being very simple, the others not.  The results  take 20.6 MB.   I tried saving the result in two ways

```
Save["cfp.m", cfp]
DumpSave["cfp.mx", cfp]
```

''Save'' produces a file of 2852 Ko;
trying to open it by clicking on it crashes the file which produced the expression.
''DumpSave'' produces a file of 38 Ko containing only the word Null.

Thanks for all the  answers, I haven't tried them yet, it seemed that first priority  was to give the full example. It is worrisome that DumpSave works on other computers, but not on mine

Comment: did you try DumpSave?  see [how-do-i-save-a-variable-or-function-definition-to-a-file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/how-do-i-save-a-variable-or-function-definition-to-a-file)

Comment: Similar results. For the long expression a 1Ko file (probably empty file) was created. For the shorter,  a 58Ko file was created. It contained only the word Null. I guess there are some limits to what can be saved under my Mathematica Setup

Comment: Nasser is right to say that you should be using something like `DumpSave["filename.mx", expression]`, that works. You say that doesn't work for you, i.e something that does works for other people doesn't work for you. That hints  there is a problem in the way you are implementing the solution. We can only speculate, unless you provide a minimum working example of your problem. Please [edit] your question and provide a minimal well-formatted *Mathematica* code example of how you are saving your data.

Comment: If your file is empty, is possible you are doing something like `DumpSave["filename.mx", expression;]` (notice the extra `;`). Is that the case?

Comment: I have run your code, and `DumpSave["cfp.mx", cfp]` does produce a 33.8KB file with the correct data.  It's not empty. It starts with `"(*This is a Wolfram Language binary dump file. It can be loaded with Get.*)"` then it becomes binary.

Comment: Similar problems have reappeared with an .m file obtained by Save (I continued to use Save, because I could not find any discussion in the documentation of when DumpSave improves on Save. The current problem involves an .m file which cannot be opened, any attempt to do this crashes the Mathematica, with a last message of "this content can only be opened with more recent versions" (I have 13.1)

Answer (score -1):

Try

book= ToString[expression];
Export[Environment["userprofile"]<>"\Desktop\book.txt",book]

and open it in WordPad.

Its not even difficult to StringReplace the commas or other special strings like    " "x__~~":="  -> Newline<>x<>":="
in order to insert line breaks. Can be done in the Export command.

Comment: How do you know `ToString` and `"Text"` format is relevant here? I fail to see how this answer is relevant. `Export` if for changing format, which was not mentioned by the OP.

Comment: Its the lasr possibility remainig,  to check an expression by eye,  that not is triggering Mathematica to look at the content. If ToString crashes, there will be a very serious problem in the system. Export of Mathemarica formats does some interpreting. In vs 13 Windows is crashing for me on numerous tasks, even a search for a .nb in Windows explorer.

Comment: In that case,  Is this is more like a comment than an answer? You don't say that your is a strategy to troubleshoot. It reads like an answer that missed the point. Probably you could edit it to improve it.

Comment: No, you are missing the point. Import and Export as plain text is always the sure way. Like the context menu by mouse right click and choice  'SaveAs' as the last exit before you have to kill the kernel.

Comment: @rhermans while I agree this response could stand some improvement, as a work-around it does make sense. One would want to use InputForm in converting to a string though (if it’s not the default setting).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau `InputForm` is very different from `ToString` which is a non-reversible transformation. I still think this is not a good answer.

Comment: @rhermans Often (though I'm sure not always) `ToExpression[ToString[expr,InputForm]]` will round-trip. So it might be "good enough", depending on specifics of what is being saved. In this case I gather it is a set of complicate solutions from `Solve`. I would expect it to work for that. This of course does not get at the original issue, as to whether or why using the stated `*Save` methods is not performing to expectations. But as a workaround maybe it suffices?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau `ToExpression@ToString[a^3]` is not a round-trip, `ToExpression[ToString[a^3, InputForm]]` is, but that is not what this answers offers.

Comment: @rhermans Cue "while I agree this response could stand some improvement..."