# Is it possible that an attempt to `Save` damages a file to the extent that further work on it becomes impossible?

Tags: warning-messages, save

I have a history of my Mathematica 13.1 having problems sometimes when I try to `Save` or `DumpSave` variables with long formulas -- see [Problems with 'DumpSave' and 'Save' in Mathematica 13.1 on Windows 11](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285319/problems-with-dumpsave-and-save-in-mathematica-13-1-on-windows-11?noredirect=1#comment710446_285319) . Similar problems have reappeared today after trying to Save an .m file   (I continue to use Save, because I could not find any discussion in the documentation of when  Save should be avoided, or of how DumpSave improves on it). The current problem involved an .m file which could not be opened, any attempt to do this crashing the Mathematica, with a last message of "this content can only be opened with more recent versions" . Even after erasing that file and restarting the computer, normal work with the rest of the file which had produced this headache became impossible. Things seem to work briefly, but then anodine operations end up in temporary freezes acompamied by messages `Operation de formatage en cours'