# Saving lengthy calculation results in Mathematica for future use

Tags: functions, save

I've got a really long list that's the result of a complex calculation. I'd like to save it in a way that I can use it again when I start a new session in Mathematica, without having to redo all the previous calculations. Is there a good way to do this? Simply copying and saving it using the short format won't work when you open it with a new kernel. If you copy everything using the 'Show All' option and then assigning it to a new variable, which seems to work, but it's quite lengthy and not very convenient.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at `DumpSave`?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks, that seemed useful. However, I couldn't make it work. Is this correct? `data = Range[1000000];
DumpSave["datafile.mx", data];
loadedData = << datafile.mx;
loadedData[[4]] == 4`

Comment: How large is the result? Another option could be to use `Iconize`.

Also "variable = << filename" is wrong, but "variable = Get[filename]" may work.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino I think it's around 500kB with a list of ~100k elements.

Comment: @hana, please see [Reading and Writing Wolfram System Files](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FilesStreamsAndExternalOperations.html#14387).

Comment: See also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1959/1871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the comment: `DumpSave` works by storing the definitions of symbols. These definitions will be restored when you `Get` the `.mx` file. So a typical workflow would be:

```
data = Range[1000000];

DumpSave["datafile.mx", data];

Clear[data]

ByteCount[data]

Get["datafile.mx"]

ByteCount[data]
```

Note how the `Get["datafile.mx"]` simply restores the old definition of `data`. This also works with functions etc.

Comment: Thank you. I have just figured it out as well. I read somewhere that the saved file may not be compatible with a different computer, operating system, or version of Mathematica.
Is there a setting to ensure that it always works on different PCs or versions?

Comment: No, not for `DumpSave`. If you need a platform-independent method, use `Save`, though this might be inefficient for large data. Large data you can store in a file using the [WXF](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/WXF.html) format. So it would be something like `Export["data.wxf", data]` and `data = Import["data.wxf"]`.