# Precision of interpolation function after exporting and importing

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, export, interpolation

I've solved a differential equation using `NDSolve` with a large working precision `prec`. The output is a few interpolating functions which, when evaluated, return values with the same working precision specified before.

I'd like to export these functions to avoid rerunning `NDSolve`. I landed on using

```
Export["fun.m", f[x]]
```

for exporting the function and

```
f[x_] = Import["fun.m"]
```

to import the function. *However*, after importing, the values returned by `f[x]` are always given by the `MachinePrecision`. Taking `Precision[f[x]]`  also returns `MachinePrecision`.

I've taken a look at the exported `.m` files and it looks like all of the data is there, so I am not sure what the issue is.

Here is a minimal example:

```
f = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 20];

Export["fun.m", f];
fExported = Import["fun.m"];

f[1] // FullForm
(* 2.71828181220202324036957913881075389703`19.68219897174271 *)
fExported[1] // FullForm
(* 2.718281812202023`*)
```

Comment: `fExported // InputForm` and `FilePrint["fun.m"]` show the problem is probably with `Import`. The values at the end of "fun.m" are at the correct precision, but they are machine precision in `fExported`. It's either a bug or there's some option to `Import` you should use (don't know what that is, though). Using `"fun.mx"` seems to fix the problem, if that's any help.

Comment: What seems to work is using [`DumpSave`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html) instead of `Export`. See also [How do I save a variable or function definition to a file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/how-do-i-save-a-variable-or-function-definition-to-a-file).

Comment: Actually `foo = First@Import[funFile, "HeldExpressions"]` shows `Import` does its job right. But `ReleaseHold[foo]` shows that the evaluation of `InterpolatingFunction` converts the values to machine precision. I'd say it's a bug and should be reported to WRI.

Comment: Please report this to WRI.

Answer (score 6):

This reproduces the behavior without using `Export` or `Import`:

```
f[1]//FullForm
(InterpolatingFunction@@f)[1]//FullForm
(*
2.7182818284590670945608961396241485466543375144201657067031`29.698970004336015
2.7182818284590673`
*)
```

The ".mx" file format, used by `DumpSave`, is a system-dependent file format that saves a binary version of the definitions of a symbol that does not have the bug above. The ".wxf" and ".wdx" formats seem to have the same evaluation of `InterpolatingFunction` problem as ".m".

Wolfram Language File Formats: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WolframLanguageFileFormats.html

---

*Update: Potential workaround*

Changing the interpolation method seems to avoid the bug, at a cost of some memory and a little time:

```
f = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 2}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 20]; // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.00133956, Null} *)

fAll = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 2}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
    InterpolationOrder -> All]; // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.0014855, Null} *)


ByteCount /@ {f, fAll}

(* {19656, 47656} *)

Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "fun.m"}], fAll];
fAllExported = Import[%];
fAllExported[1]

(* 2.7182818308898678447 *)
```