# Failed to retrieve raw data from importing InterpolatingFunction derived from NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, export, import, finite-element-method

I tried numerically solving a set of time-dependent PDEs with variables `{u, v, w}` by `NDSolve` over 2 regions with 2D grids, generated by FEM. The solution was exported to hard drive in the format of `InterpolatingFunction`. But as I import from the saved file, the code fails to retrieve the stored data.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
dr = 0.5 10^-0; rx = 2./2  10^-0; xs = -(dr + rx); ys = 0.0;
ec = RegionUnion[Disk[{-rx, 0}, dr], Rectangle[{-rx, -dr}, {rx, dr}], 
   Disk[{rx, 0}, dr]];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[ec, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> .05];
bmesh["Wireframe"];
f = Function[{vertices, area}, 
   area > 0.002 (1. - 0.5 Norm[Mean[vertices]])];
(mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MeshRefinementFunction -> f])["Wireframe"]
ndr = 0.3 10^-0; nrx = 
 1.2/2  10^-0; nxs = -(ndr + nrx); nys = 0.0; nlx = 0.4/1  10^-0;
nc = RegionUnion[Disk[{-nrx, 0}, ndr], 
   Rectangle[{-nrx, -ndr}, {(-nrx + nlx), ndr}], 
   Disk[{(-nrx + nlx), 0}, ndr], Disk[{(nrx - nlx), 0}, ndr], 
   Rectangle[{(nrx - nlx), -ndr}, {nrx, ndr}], Disk[{nrx, 0}, ndr]];
rPC = 0.00  10^-0;
xPC1 = rx + (dr - 1*rPC)*Cos[1 Pi/4]; yPC1 = (dr - 1*rPC)*
  Sin[1 Pi/4];
xPC2 = -rx - (dr - 1*rPC)*Cos[-Pi/3]; yPC2 = (dr - 1*rPC)*Sin[-Pi/3];
PtChg1 = Disk[{xPC1, yPC1}, rPC];
PtChg2 = Disk[{xPC2, yPC2}, rPC];
PtChg = RegionUnion[PtChg1, PtChg2];
Show[Region[Style[nc, Cyan]], mesh["Wireframe"], 
 Graphics[{Magenta, Thick, PointSize[0.01], Point[{xPC1, yPC1}], 
   Point[{xPC2, yPC2}]}]]
Ck0 = 139.20  10^9; Ccl0 = 12.43  10^9; 
u0 = Ck0/Ck0;
v0 = Ccl0/Ck0;
dk = 1.95  10^3; dcl = 2.02  10^3; 
d0 = dcl/dk;
Tend = 0.0001 ;
V2 = -0.05*37.436;  
q = 516.75  10^9; rho = (q/(\[Pi]  ndr^2 + 4  ndr  nrx) )/( Ck0);
Eqs = Inactivate[{D[u[t, x, y], 
      t] - (Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
       Div[(u[t, x, y])  Grad[w[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]), 
    D[v[t, x, y], t] - 
     d0 (Laplacian[v[t, x, y], {x, y}] - 
        Div[(v[t, x, y])  Grad[w[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]), 
    0.001  D[w[t, x, y], t] - Laplacian[w[t, x, y], {x, y}] - 
     4  \[Pi]  (u[t, x, y] - v[t, x, y] - 
        rho   Boole[{x, y} \[Element] nc])}, Laplacian | D];
ics = {u[0, x, y] == u0, v[0, x, y] == v0, w[0, x, y] == 0.0};
bcs = DirichletCondition[w[t, x, y] == V2, True];
sol = NDSolve[{Activate[Eqs] == {NeumannValue[0, True], 
      NeumannValue[0, True], 0}, ics, bcs}, {u, v, 
    w}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, {t, 0, Tend}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> All];
Export[FileNameJoin[{"C:\\Efield\\Expt_20240214\\a1\\K.vs.Cl-1_11.20\\", "Test1.m"}], sol];
```

```
isol = Import[FileNameJoin[{"C:\\Efield\\Expt_20240214\\a1\\K.vs.Cl-1_11.20\\", 
"Test.m"}]];
Plot[Evaluate[{u[0.0001, x, 0], v[0.0001, x, 0]} /.First[isol]], {x, -1.5, 1.5}]
Evaluate[u[0.0001, 0, 0] /. First[isol]]
```

Evaluation the value of specific points also returned no results, but shows InterpolatingFunction like

[image: ![enter image description here]

I checked the data file and it looks like

> *(* Created with the Wolfram Language : [www.wolfram.com](http://www.wolfram.com) *) {{u -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.0001}, {-1.4999999999999998, 1.5},
> {-0.5, 0.5}}, {5, 4225, 5, {42, 8018, 0}, {4, 3, 3}, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> Indeterminate & , {}, {}, False}, {{0., 1.*^-8, 2.*^-8, 4.*^-8, 8.*^-8,
> 1.6*^-7, 2.4000000000000003*^-7, 3.2*^-7, 4.800000000000001*^-7,
> 6.4*^-7, 8.*^-7, 1.1199999999999999*^-6, 1.4399999999999998*^-6,
> 2.0799999999999996*^-6, 2.6559999999999996*^-6, 3.2319999999999997*^-6,
> 3.808*^-6, 4.384*^-6, 5.536*^-6, 6.688*^-6, 8.09254755698846*^-6, ....
> *

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Very likely, the problem is that you did not define `Tend` – you see, it is displayed in blue color.

Comment: Tend was alreday defined and set to various values for trial. In the code, 0.0001 was set.

Comment: I'm looking at the screenshot you provided. In there, `Tend` is not defined. Also, does `Evaluate[v[0.0001, x, 0] /. First[isol]]` return anything?

Comment: I revised the screenshot as shown above. Evaluate[v[0.0001, x, 0] /. First[isol]] also returned the same as shown above. Thanks for your response~

Comment: We don't know what you export exactly, but maybe first you need to define interpolation function like `U=u /. First[isol]]` and then evaluate   `U[.001,0,0]`.

Comment: @Alex, I also tried to define interpolation function like you suggested and returned the same result. What I did is like "sol=NDSolve[....]; Export["Test.m",sol];".

Comment: @dopey, I strongly suggest you include the whole code for solving the equation and exporting to the question. Otherwise, it will be difficult for others to help and find the problem. For example, I've tried to make a simple example, similar to your, and my code [works as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojKDd.png). Also, try your code with a fresh kernel (by using `Quit`).

Comment: @Domen, Thanks for your help and reediting my question. I tried your example, it works well. However, it's not the case as running my code.

Comment: @dopey Your code generated file `Test1.m` of about 76.9Mb. What actually do you try to simulate?

Comment: @ Alex, The code is to simulate the initial charging process of a battery with 2 electrodes located to the cell peripheral and central region. `u` and `v` are concentrations for cations and anions respectively and `w` is electrical potential. The `Tend` here is only set to 0.0001 for demonstration, 5 is used instead in real simulation. The output size of data file is about 300-400mb. Several parametric condidtions were tuned through `ParallelDo`.

Comment: @dopey It looks like `InterpolatingFunction` retrieved from the text file `Test1.m` is some data available to use. If you like I can show how to use it.

Comment: @Alex, yes, Please show how to use it. I have to store data in files because I got other simulations with even much longer comuptations. Thanks a lot~

Comment: Use the MX format, `"Test1.mx"`.....There was another problem with `InterpolatingFunction` and the .m format [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/295837/precision-of-interpolation-function-after-exporting-and-importing). It seems a different problem, but the .m format and `InterpolatingFunction` do not seem to work well together in both cases. Maybe the bugs are related.

Comment: As a side question: Why do you Inactivate your PDE only to Activate it later again?

Comment: This looks a bit like a bug, you should send it to WRI: support@wolfram.com

Comment: @Goofy, it's unlikely that the bugs are related, the one is arbitrary precision code this one is machine precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know file with extension `.m` is a plain text file, therefore all data in it are available to use. For example we generate file `Test1.m` with code

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
dr = 0.5 10^-0; rx = 2./2  10^-0; xs = -(dr + rx); ys = 0.0;
ec = RegionUnion[Disk[{-rx, 0}, dr], Rectangle[{-rx, -dr}, {rx, dr}], 
   Disk[{rx, 0}, dr]];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[ec, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> .05];
bmesh["Wireframe"];
f = Function[{vertices, area}, 
   area > 0.002 (1. - 0.5 Norm[Mean[vertices]])];
(mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MeshRefinementFunction -> f])["Wireframe"]
ndr = 0.3 10^-0; nrx = 
 1.2/2  10^-0; nxs = -(ndr + nrx); nys = 0.0; nlx = 0.4/1  10^-0;
nc = RegionUnion[Disk[{-nrx, 0}, ndr], 
   Rectangle[{-nrx, -ndr}, {(-nrx + nlx), ndr}], 
   Disk[{(-nrx + nlx), 0}, ndr], Disk[{(nrx - nlx), 0}, ndr], 
   Rectangle[{(nrx - nlx), -ndr}, {nrx, ndr}], Disk[{nrx, 0}, ndr]];
rPC = 0.00  10^-0;
xPC1 = rx + (dr - 1*rPC)*Cos[1 Pi/4]; yPC1 = (dr - 1*rPC)*
  Sin[1 Pi/4];
xPC2 = -rx - (dr - 1*rPC)*Cos[-Pi/3]; yPC2 = (dr - 1*rPC)*Sin[-Pi/3];
PtChg1 = Disk[{xPC1, yPC1}, rPC];
PtChg2 = Disk[{xPC2, yPC2}, rPC];
PtChg = RegionUnion[PtChg1, PtChg2];
Show[Region[Style[nc, Cyan]], mesh["Wireframe"], 
 Graphics[{Magenta, Thick, PointSize[0.01], Point[{xPC1, yPC1}], 
   Point[{xPC2, yPC2}]}]]
Ck0 = 139.20  10^9; Ccl0 = 12.43  10^9; 
u0 = Ck0/Ck0;
v0 = Ccl0/Ck0;
dk = 1.95  10^3; dcl = 2.02  10^3; 
d0 = dcl/dk;
Tend = 0.0001 ;
V2 = -0.05*37.436;  
q = 516.75  10^9; rho = (q/(\[Pi]  ndr^2 + 4  ndr  nrx) )/( Ck0);
Eqs = Inactivate[{D[u[t, x, y], 
      t] - (Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
       Div[(u[t, x, y])  Grad[w[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]), 
    D[v[t, x, y], t] - 
     d0 (Laplacian[v[t, x, y], {x, y}] - 
        Div[(v[t, x, y])  Grad[w[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]), 
    0.001  D[w[t, x, y], t] - Laplacian[w[t, x, y], {x, y}] - 
     4  \[Pi]  (u[t, x, y] - v[t, x, y] - 
        rho   Boole[{x, y} \[Element] nc])}, Laplacian | D];
ics = {u[0, x, y] == u0, v[0, x, y] == v0, w[0, x, y] == 0.0};
bcs = DirichletCondition[w[t, x, y] == V2, True];
sol = NDSolve[{Activate[Eqs] == {NeumannValue[0, True], 
      NeumannValue[0, True], 0}, ics, bcs}, {u, v, 
    w}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, {t, 0, Tend}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> All];
Export[FileNameJoin[{"C:\\...\\", "Test1.m"}], sol];
```

Then we load this file with

```
isol = Import["C:\\...\\Test1.m"]
```

As output we have for example in v.12.2
[image: Figure 1]

And in v.14.0.0 it looks like
[image: Figure 2]

Obviously in different versions `InterpolatingFunction` looks different. Nevertheless it is just data stored in it, and we can try to retrieve data as follows

```
{U, V, W} = {u, v, w} /. isol[[1]];
```

First we check time table

```
time = U[[3, 1]]

(*Out[]= {0., 1.*10^-8, 2.*10^-8, 4.*10^-8, 8.*10^-8, 1.6*10^-7, 
 2.4*10^-7, 3.2*10^-7, 4.8*10^-7, 6.4*10^-7, 8.*10^-7, 1.12*10^-6, 
 1.44*10^-6, 2.08*10^-6, 2.656*10^-6, 3.232*10^-6, 3.808*10^-6, 
 4.384*10^-6, 5.536*10^-6, 6.688*10^-6, 8.09255*10^-6, 
 9.4971*10^-6, 0.0000109016, 0.0000123062, 0.0000137107, \
0.0000151153, 0.0000179244, 0.0000207335, 0.0000235426, 0.0000263517, \
0.0000291608, 0.000034779, 0.0000403971, 0.0000460153, 0.0000516335, \
0.0000572517, 0.0000628699, 0.0000684881, 0.0000741063, 0.0000841063, \
0.0000941063, 0.0001}*)
```

Now we can prepare `InterpolatingFunction` for example at `t=0.0001`, or last element `time[[-1]]` as follows

```
u0001 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, U[[4]][[-1, 1]]]

v0001 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, V[[4]][[-1, 1]]]

w0001 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, W[[4]][[-1, 1]]]
```

Finally plot data

```
{Plot3D[u0001[x, y], Element[{x, y}, mesh], ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot3D[v0001[x, y], Element[{x, y}, mesh], ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot3D[w0001[x, y], Element[{x, y}, mesh], ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 3]

Please note, in different versions `mesh` generated in different ways, so that `mesh` from v.12.x.x is not same as in v.14.0.0. If we have no `mesh` available as above, then we can retrieve mesh elements from `isol` as follows

```
points=U[[3, 2]][[1]]
```

In v.14 we have output
[image: Figure 4]

```
ListPlot[points]
```

[image: Figure 5]

Triangle elements

```
 triel=U[[3, 2]][[2]]
```

[image: Figure6]

Line elements

```
linel=U[[3, 2]][[3]]
```

Point Elements

```
pointel=U[[3, 2]][[4]]
```

In v.14 run first

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
```

Then we can generate mesh as

```
mesh1= U[[3, 2]]

(*Out[]= ElementMesh[{{-1.5, 1.5}, {-0.5, 0.5}}, {TriangleElement[
   "<" 3917 ">"]}]*)
```

Then we can use `mesh1` as above, for example for `t=time[[-2]]` we have

```
u0002 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh1}, U[[4]][[-2, 1]]];

v0002 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh1}, V[[4]][[-2, 1]]];

w0002 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh1}, W[[4]][[-2, 1]]];
```

Visualization

```
{Plot3D[u0002[x, y], Element[{x, y}, mesh1], ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot3D[v0002[x, y], Element[{x, y}, mesh1], ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot3D[w0002[x, y], Element[{x, y}, mesh1], ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 7]

Answer (score 2):

Export/import with ".m" files does not (it seems) preserve packed arrays. But `InterpolatingFunction` relies (it seems) on some of its data arrays being packed. I suggest that one consider using ".mx" files instead; they do not have this problem.

The following repairs the bug. (It seems to pack more arrays than are packed in the original solution, but it produces a working solution.)

```
jsol = isol /. 
   a_?(ArrayQ[#, _, NumericQ] &) :> Developer`ToPackedArray[a];

ByteCount /@ {isol, jsol}

(* {80590000, 27442504} *)

u[0.0001, 0, 0] /. First[jsol]

(* 1.00143 *)

Plot[Evaluate[{u[0.0001, x, 0], v[0.0001, x, 0]} /. 
   First[jsol]], {x, -1.5, 1.5}]
```

[image]