Precision loss when assigning to the elements of a list interpolation function during ParallelDo
Bug introduced after 8.0.4, persisting through 14.1.

A minimal working example of the phenomenon is the following code:
rulef = Range[2];
SetSharedVariable[rulef, ruler];
ParallelDo[
  Clear[templist];
  templist = Table[{p, SetPrecision[RandomReal[], 20]}, {p, Range[5]}];
  rulef[[t]] = Interpolation[templist][k];
  test[k_] = Interpolation[templist][k];
  Print[Precision[rulef[[t]][SetPrecision[3.1, 20]]]];
  Print[Precision[test[SetPrecision[3.1, 20]]]];
  , {t, Range[2]}];

I am interpolating some data which depend (IRL) on the parameter t. I want to save each of the InterpolatingFunctions into a list, here called rulef. As it turns out, even if the InterpolatingFunction has precision 19, when saving it to a list, the element suddenly becomes machineprecision. Is there a reason for that? And can one circumvent this? I.e. is there perhaps a smater way than saving the InterpolatingFunctions into a list shared between all kernels? (The list is IRL a list of rules that replace coefficients by the InterpolatingFunctions)
EDIT: This seems to be an issue of ParallelDo. Using Do gives the expected behaviour instead.

This reminds me of Precision of interpolation function after exporting and importing.

@Domen So I should do InterpolationOrder->All ? This seems to be a bit slow for the actual thing. (Since I need to integrate a lot of those things with products of each other) EDIT: It doesnt work either though

This seems to be an issue of Parallel. ParallelEvaluate[Interpolation[{1/2, 2/3, 4/5, 5/6}], 1] // Precision will give MachinePrecision too, even if only one kernel is specified for computation.

Do you know a workaround? Not being able to parallelize without losing precision is kind of a death sentence if I want to be more precise.

I have tried some more things and now I'm more inclined to think the issue lies with the InterpolatingFunction itself. If you run f = Interpolation[{1/2, 1/3, 1/5, 1/7}], then f // Precision will give Infinity as expected. However, if you copy the output cell and measure the precision of the copy, you will get MachinePrecision. I believe this is the same issue as the comment from Goofy in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/295837/precision-of-interpolation-function-after-exporting-and-importing.

@houzw i did see that question. But the workaround posted there does not work in this case.

@Confuse-ray30 I believe this is a bug in InterpolatingFunction, so there is no easy workaround. However, another more important question is whether parallelism can really speed up your problem. According to my test, ParallelTable is significantly slower than Table, unless there are tens of thousands of interpolation points for each InterpolatingFunction.

@houzw you mean Do instead of ParallelDo? Could it be that you only tried with 2 points in t? (In my MWE the list is just two elements, and then it is true that parallelization is slower since it has to first give the subkernels the task etc. But imagine hundred points.)

@Confuse-ray30 Well, I don't know why you chose to use Do instead of Table to build a list. However, this will not change the fact that parallelism is slower. Don't imagine, give it a try.

@houzw I chose ParallelDo because in the parallelization, some other things happen first before interpolating. I'll try using just Do then

@houzw You are correct (for 32 points, 8 kernels)! And I don't know why parallelization takes longer. I'll have to test it out for the actual thing, although given I don't have any alternatives, it doesn't really matter.
