# OpenSQLConnection problem - password visible

Tags: databaselink, sql, security

**Prerequisites**

- some database (here, it's called sakila (mysql standard test db I think))
- a user (with password) that has access to that db (I'll use u:testuser/p:testpass)

**Setup - minimal (?) working example**

We call

```
 Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
```

Next we shall use the wizard/connection tool to create a new database connection, like:

```
c1 = OpenSQLConnection[]
```

[image]

(after creating the new connection, we use the wizard to connect right to the new connection; and obviously, we do **not** tick the "store password in plain text").

Next, we set up another connection:

```
c2 = OpenSQLConnection["test"]
```

where `"test"` is the name we used for above connection (we get prompted for the password).

Finally, a third connection:

```
c3 = OpenSQLConnection[
    JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)", "localhost:3306/sakila"], 
    "Catalog" -> Automatic, "Description" -> None, "Name" -> "test", 
    "Password" -> "$Prompt", "Properties" -> {}, "ReadOnly" -> False, 
    "RelativePath" -> False, 
    "TransactionIsolationLevel" -> "ReadUncommitted", 
    "UseConnectionPool" -> False, "Username" -> "testuser", 
    "Version" -> 2.]
```

(this is exactly copy/paste from the .m file created by the wizard, using `OpenSQLConnection` instead of `SQLConnection`. You can check the `FullForm` of `c1` or `c2` to find its location, on MacOSX, standard: "/Users/username/Library/Mathematica/DatabaseResources/test.m").

And maybe a last one (choose `"test"` in the GUI):

```
c4 = OpenSQLConnection[]
```

**The Problem**

Execute:

```
Cases[#, HoldPattern[Rule["Password", ___]], Infinity] & /@ {c1, c2, c3, c4}
```

> {{"Password" -> "testpass"}, {"Password" -> "\$Prompt"}, 
>   {"Password" ->"\$Prompt"}, {"Password" -> "testpass"}}

i.e., `c1` and `c4` (the connections I **opened** with `OpenSQLConnection[]` (without argument)) are sharing my password in plain text!

**My Question**

Is this a known behaviour? I was using `OpenSQLConnection[]` (using the GUI) frequently, am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**
See @Murta's answer for an example where the password is visible without using the GUI.

Answer (score 4):

When I have to connect frequently to a database, I prefer to create a pack with the connections strings.

```
BeginPackage["myConn`",{"DatabaseLink`"}]

myConn::usage="myConn[ip] with default 192.168.0.20";

Begin["`Private`"]

myConn[ip_:"192.168.0.20"] := 
  OpenSQLConnection[
   JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)", ip], 
   "Username" -> "my User", 
   "Password" -> Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPChZgYGDIrXTOz8tLTS7JzM8LSCwuBgBdFAg1"] ];

SetAttributes[marcheConn, {ReadProtected,Locked}];
(*Locked is important to don't permit ReadProtected to be undone*)

End[]
EndPackage[]
```

Then I encode the package as you can see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30839/2266) to protect the package content.

I can now use my connection as in this example:

```
Needs["myConn`"]
conn=myConn[]
data=SQLExecute[conn,"select * from tabX"]
CloseSQLConnection[conn]
```

**Update**

As commented by @PinguinDirk you can get all `conn` information (password and login) simple executing `conn`. I wrote to Wolfram Enterprise Support that answered:

> I want to let you know that we were able to reproduce that the password was visible when the FullForm of the expression is requested in Mathematica (or the execution of conn).  Currently, we are unable to uncover a method that would protect this information from being visible in a Mathematica session once the connection has been established.

Maybe in version 10. I have officially suggested it.

Comment: Thanks for this approach - one problem: when I do so (created package (mySQL connection), encoded it, opened that connection), the password is still visible in `FullForm` (even `Uncompressed`). Can you confirm that this is the case for you too? ... maybe I did something wrong, just want to make sure, and try again

Comment: @PinguinDirk you are right! Let me think about. I'll try some help from Wolfram support.

Comment: I find it rather scary... let me know what Wolfram thinks, I'll wait to write them until I hear back from you. Thanks for the effort

Comment: I have all interest in this problem. I came back as soon  as I get some news from Enterprise Support.

Comment: Thanks for the update - currently I connect to my db's in a way like `c2` or `c3` in my post, and then the password is not visible... (as I don't store those important passwords, this is a valuable option for me, i.e. using `"$Prompt"`). So I am more or less safe, but well, they better fix this for all sorts of ways to connect.

Comment: In the meantime doesn't closing con inside the package avoid this problem?  i.e. just pass a sql string to the package, SQLExecute it in the package, and pass back only the result.  Ok its a little inefficient if you have multiple SQL statements to run but avoids the issue if you don't want to use $Prompt.