# Run encoded package code through .NET/Link?

Tags: packages, .netlink

An earlier question of mine, [Prevent package from being opened in a notebook interface](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46664/prevent-package-from-being-opened-in-a-notebook-interface), never received an answer, but [Albert Retey's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/169/albert-retey) comments did lead me to an entirely different solution.

To secure my Mathematica code for distribution to a client I now plan to wrap encoded Mathematica code in C# code and compile it to a DLL.  The client will then call the DLL from their .NET application with specific methods that will call my proprietary Mathematica functions.  My compiled code will handle all .NET/Link operations.

Wrapping encoded code in a DLL may seem like overkill (well I still tie double knots in my shoelaces).  I just want to make the code as secure as possible and as I have to do the compiling on my client's Window's machine (I use Mac) I want to do everything to keep it from curious eyes.

I've written a package and encoded it.  I've tested the package in the client environment by loading the encoded package file from a notebook interface.  This works fine.

I've done a second test.  In a notebook, I copied the encoded text and pasted it into a cell and assigned it to a variable, something like:

```
myEncodedString = "(*!1N!*)mcm
j<hTJue'P+lKh]7t>X#r/N5>m^c0Q j,fdE~0y@X>TkncC'AMluD1_R3,0?vQR0(n|p08B
D\O%!1o3t~`#0VL...a bunch more encoded text..."
```

Following this I tried:

```
Get[myEncodedString]
```

This didn't work.  I revisited what I needed to do and realized I could make it work by using the form `Get[stream]` and tried the following:

```
Get@StringToStream[myEncodedString]
```

This gave me the following dialogue box:

[image]

Selecting "Yes" ran the code and made all of its function definitions available.

Now I tried to do the same thing from C# via .NET/Link, which did not work.
I think it didn't work because I need some way to insert escapes in the encoded text.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this or more generally how to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easy way to achieve what you want. First, let's load some sample package, encode it and re-import it as string:

```
file = FileNames["Collatz.m", {$InstallationDirectory}, Infinity];
encoded = ToFileName[$TemporaryDirectory, "encoded"];
Encode[First[file], encoded];
encCode = Import[encoded, "Text"]

(* mcmM$RqUiqylb8ORSH!A>J.... *)
```

After that it is as easy as

```
ImportString[encCode, "Package"]
```

and you can test by calling `??Collatz` that the package was loaded successfully.

Comment: Let me make certain, I follow your solution and perhaps clarify it for others.  Using something like `myEncodedString=ImportString[encCode, "Package"]` gives me a proper string equivalent of the encoded package.  Next I can copy that string into the C# code with the `Get@StringToStream[myEncodedString]` (because the `Get[]` will still need a stream?) or will `myEncodedString` execute directly? I ask because I don't have access to a Windows machine to test the C# NET/Link over the weekend.

Comment: @Jagra `ImportString[encCode,"Package"]` is equivalent to using `Get` on a file containing the encoded package. Therefore, `ImportString[encCode, "Package"]` **evaluates** the package code and after this call your function definitions are available (like Collatz[..] here). It doesn't give you a string.

Comment: OK, if I follow, this should get me past the dialogue box when running this from a notebook, but I don't yet see a clear way to get this to run from the C# Net/Link world. As you pointed out in your answer to [Prevent package from being opened in a notebook interface](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46664/prevent-package-from-being-opened-in-a-notebook-interface)?, I don't want a package (encoded or not) file sitting around somewhere accessible to spelunking. Thoughts? Explanation? Is your `WolframLibrary` idea, from the referenced answer, a better approach? –

Comment: You can translate the WolframLibrary idea directly into NETLink. The code I used to inject the encoded package into the C code and load it from within the library call can be done in almost exactly the same way in NETLink. You will find everything you need in [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NETLink/tutorial/CallingMathematicaFromNET.html).

Comment: If you want to discuss some details then we could meet in [chat]. I guess I have some time in about 2 hours (7 pm UTC).

Comment: The risk of having the file on disk and available for examination is significantly lessened by specifying a key when `Encode`ing it. You then only need to keep the key in the .NET library, not the entire package.

Comment: @OleksandrR. The overall goal is to compile the string of the package code directly into the library like asked [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47577/187). This question here was AFAIK only a sub-question on the way to this goal. What I suggest in the other answer is to compile the package code to have a further level of obfuscation because an attacker would need to (1) decompile the library to extract the package-string, (2) crack `Encode` to make it plain text again. Btw, do you have a mail-adress? Would you send me a mail (you'll find my address) which I can answer?

Comment: I emailed you. :)

Comment: Thanks for the offer to chat, but I think I've got a way forward at this point (I might ping you later:-).  I'll report back on my progress.  Again, a great idea.  Actually two great ideas.